# "Isola felice": che significa?

Tags: meaning

"A causa di quest'ultimo provvedimento il nostro quartiere potrebbe restare l'unica isola felice di tutta la città."
Vorrei tradurre "isola felice" in inglese ma devo capire il significato.

Comment: Sarebbe utile sapere a cosa si riferisce il provvedimento, in quanto "isola felice" si può tradurre con "*island of [something]*", dove "*[something]*" è ciò che rende unico quel quartiere rispetto agli altri. Ad esempio, se fosse un'isola felice er via del verde pubblico, potresti usare "*the last island of public green*"; se ci si riferisse al benessere economico, potresti usare "*the last island of wealth*"; se il riferimento è la pace/l'inquinamento acustico, "*the last island of peace/quite*", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come senza dubbio sai, *isola felice* si può tradurre letteralmente come *happy island*. Questa però non è una buona traduzione perché non rispetta l'uso metaforico che se ne fa in italiano.

Di solito *isola felice* viene usato come espressione per indicare un'area che è l'unica tra tutte quelle che la circondano a conservare (o ad aver mai avuto) qualche caratteristica positiva. Un esempio a caso rubato da [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=72LrBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&dq=%22isola+felice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ2L--g5zuAhUzwAIHHTmuB4U4RhDoATAJegQIBRAC#v=onepage&q=%22isola%20felice%22&f=false):

> La Maker Faire è il più grande evento di innovazione al mondo [...]. **Isola felice** del terzo millennio è qui che questi ultimi mostrano i progetti a cui stanno lavorando [...].

In questo caso il testo vuole sottolineare il carattere straordinario della Maker Faire, non condiviso da altri eventi simili.

Comment: Concordo (ovviamente) con la spiegazione del significato di "isola felice" però, in sei anni di permanenza in Gran Bretagna, non ho mai sentito l'espressione "*happy island*" usata con quell'accezione, mentre è piuttosto comune l'uso di "*island of ...*" quindi sarei più propenso a tradurre "isola felice" con "*island of happiness*"

Comment: @secan Forse non era chiaro, ma non suggerivo assolutamente di usare *happy island* che concordo non avere assolutamente questa connotazione in inglese (non saprei riguardo *island of happyness*, a me risulta un'espressione strana ma forse è una differenza tra l'inglese statunitense e quello britannico).

Comment: domando scusa, ho male interpretato io. Concordo che anche "*island of happiness*" non sia ideale, come traduzione; che sarebbe più opportuno usare "*island of ...*" seguita da qualunque sia la caratteristica per cui il quartiere è considerato un'isola felice.

Comment: Forse un sinonimo di "isola felice' potrebbe essere "oasi"?  Un esempio: Questo luogo e un' oasi della felicita' (isola felice)